# Unittests failing when run in series

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, easymock

I am working on writing junit tests.  I am reality new to `EasyMock` and not finding much help in the errors I am receiving.  More than likely it is due to my lack of familiarity.

When I run a single test in isolation each of the following tests pass.  When I run all tests in a class they pass.  However when I run my entire test suite using Eclipse I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: 2 matchers expected, 3 recorded.
This exception usually occurs when matchers are mixed with raw values when recording a method:
    foo(5, eq(6));  // wrong
You need to use no matcher at all or a matcher for every single param:
    foo(eq(5), eq(6));  // right
    foo(5, 6);  // also right
```

Unit Test

```
package com.example.api.rs.asset.handler;

import org.easymock.EasyMock;
import org.easymock.EasyMockRunner;
import org.easymock.Mock;
import org.easymock.TestSubject;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import com.example.api.data.JsonString;
import com.example.api.impl.AssetApiImpl;
import com.example.api.impl.PolicyApiImpl;

@RunWith(EasyMockRunner.class)
public class RsAssetApiHandlerTest {

  @TestSubject
  private final RsAssetApiHandler handler = new RsAssetApiHandler();

  @Mock
  PolicyApiImpl policyApi = null;

  @Mock
  AssetApiImpl assetApi = null;

  @Test
  public void testGetAsset() {
    // Arrange
    JsonString expected = new JsonString();
    expected.setJson("someString");

    EasyMock.expect(assetApi.assetGetAsset(0)).andReturn(expected);
    EasyMock.replay(assetApi);

    // Act
    JsonString actual = handler.getAsset(assetApi, 0);

    // Assert

    Assert.assertEquals(expected, actual);
    EasyMock.verify(assetApi);
  }

  @Test
  public void testGetDetails() {
    // Arrange
    JsonString expected = new JsonString();
    expected.setJson("someString");

    EasyMock.expect(assetApi.assetGetDetails(0, 0)).andReturn(expected);
    EasyMock.replay(assetApi);

    // Act
    JsonString actual = handler.getDetails(assetApi, 0, 0);

    // Assert

    Assert.assertEquals(expected, actual);
    EasyMock.verify(assetApi);
  }

}
```

I tried using `EasyMock.anyInt()` in my expect but it does not seem to change the outcome.  Any pointers would be appreciated.

Edit: Clarification.

When unit tests are run in isolation they pass.  When unit tests are run with the entire suite one fails and I get the `IllegalStateException`.  `testGetDetails` is the failing test.

Comment: I don't see which line has that problem.  Can you please edit your question to make that clear?

Comment: @JoeC I tried to add more but for some reason the test passes when run on their own but if I run all tests in our suite then it fails with that exception.

Comment: What are the line number(s) reported by the error?

Comment: @KarlM the line with `EasyMock.expect` in it.

Comment: I am starting to think it might be a bug with eclipse/EasyMock  I added more tests to the file and I have a new failing test  in the same class but the one failing before is now passing...

Comment: Sorry, but we can't help with such problems. If you yourself aren't able to repro any more - then what should we do about it? Besides: the one expect that you have there looks fine - as you got values for both arguments.

Comment: Oh the problem is very easy to repro.  It just changes.  That is why I am leaning to a bug in EasyMock OR the IDE.  It could even have to do with the tests are run?   I give up.  It passes outside the IDE.

Comment: Are you running tests in parallel? Which version of EasyMock are you using? Can you add a `System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName())` in your tests to see if they are running in the same thread?

Comment: @Henri easymock 3.4 and all on the same thread.

Comment: All your code is fine. Can you check the test called right before `testGetDetails`? Is `assetGetAsset` a final method?